# Amazon EC2 Micro Instance - Public DNS Not Accessible

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have created a micro instance with Ubuntu OS at Amazon EC2. But I am not able to access public DNS even after installing LAMP Server.

At my apache.conf I can see(no document configuration id available in there) --

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

Inside **sites-enabled** I have two files -- **default** & **default-ssl**.

Default contains

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

My **apache2** is running at server & **/VAR/WWW/** contains a *index.php* file, where I have written some dummy code for testing.

I tried browsing about it & read somewhere to add a rule in INBOUND for DNS with source `0.0.0.0/0`. That also I did, but still when I am trying to access the public DNS it comes "This webpage is not available".

Comment: What are you using to "access" the "public DNS"?

Comment: @Dannie I am trying to access it in browser. I can SSH it by using my .pem file

Comment: can you ping any address, like say www.google.com?

Comment: I have resolved it by adding HTTP rule in my security group.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on your instance
2. Scroll down to the information section at the bottom fo the page
3. in the tab "Description", find "Security groups"
4. click on each one of them, or the only one
5. At the "Inbound" tab click "Edit"
6. click "Add Rule"
7. Type -> select HTTP, Source -> Anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding HTTP rules in security group of the instance.

Note :- Got help from **##aws** IRC channel.